# Groovy - difference between get and propertyMissing?

Tags: groovy

There is something that I am missing. From what I have seen, *get* is the last resort if there is no property, accessor or *getProperty* available. In effect, doesn't this mean the *get* and *propertyMissing* do the same thing? I know that *get* extends the field-access operator so there must be something going on there :-)

```
// Using get
class Foo {
    def name = 'Jahg'
    Object get(String name) {
        'called get'
    }
}

def f1 = new Foo()
assert f1.noexist == 'called get'
// get() is not called for the known property (name)
assert f1.name == 'Jahg'

// Using propertyMissing
class Bar {
    Object propertyMissing(String name) {
        'called propertyMissing'
    }
}

def f2 = new Bar()
assert f2.noexist == 'called propertyMissing'

// When both are defined, get() takes precedence
class Baz  {

    // This one is called
    Object get(String name) {
        'called get'
    }

    Object propertyMissing(String name) {
        'not called'
    }
}

def f3 = new Baz()
assert f3.noexist == 'called get'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no, they're not the same, as is evidenced by the following:

```
class Baz  {
    String name = 'bob'

    Object propertyMissing(String name) {
        'not called'
    }
}

Baz b = new Baz()
assert b.getProperty('name') == 'bob'
assert b.getProperty('whatever') == 'not called'
assert b.name == 'bob'
assert b.whatever == 'not called'
```

The normal get (and getProperty) method checks to see if the property exists, then calls propertyMissing if it doesn't.

When you overloaded get, you lost the propertyMissing functionality.

Comment: Thanks that explains it