# Groovy invoking unintended "get(String)" method in script's base class

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I have a small program that lets its user execute arbitrary Groovy code. I use a base `groovy.lang.Script` class that provides a number of methods, of which one is named `get`. All this code is written in Java.

**Base class:**

```
import groovy.lang.Script;
public class ScriptClass extends Script {

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        return null;
    }

    //many other methods

    public String get(String uri) {
        System.out.println("get called with '" + uri + "'");
        return uri;
    }
}
```

The `get(String)` method above is intended to be an alias for `http(method=GET)`.

**Groovy shell invocation:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompilerConfiguration compilerConfiguration = new CompilerConfiguration();
    compilerConfiguration.setScriptBaseClass(ScriptClass.class.getName());

    GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(compilerConfiguration);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("no", "NO");

    String template = "yes";
    Script script = groovyShell.parse(template);
    script.setBinding(new Binding(map));

    Object res = script.run();
    System.out.println(res);
}
```

And that outpus:

> get called with 'yes'
>   
>  yes

The method is **not** called when I change the input code:

```
String template = "no";
```

I couldn't find any explanation to why this method is being called, maybe I missed some documentation paragraph.

**The questions**:

- Why is Groovy calling `ScriptClass.get(String)` when the script references a variable not defined in the binding?
- If this behavior is standard/correct, is there a way to prevent the resolution of undefined variables from being routed to `ScriptClass.get(String)`?

Comment: No idea how your script can return anything but null as it does nothing more than return null from it's run method. What would you expect if you parse "yes" or "no"? Usually you parse some kind of DSL, well, meaningful groovy code for the script's context. Maybe something missing in the question?

Comment: @chriopp This is a simplified version just to reproduce the problem. The actual code is more complex; but this recreates the error. Actual scripts do more than just reading `yes` and `no` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your get method disturbs the metaprogramming abilities of groovy. See [Groovy - difference between get and propertyMissing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636571). Quote: `When you overloaded get, you lost the propertyMissing functionality.`

In your example the template is always evaluated. With the template being `no` the script returns `NO`, which is defined in the binding. With the template being `yes` the unbound variable `yes` is evaluated, which, being unbound, usually always results in calling `get` and `propertyMissing` but breaks because `get` is overridden in your script.

You will have to resort to a different method name for `get` in your script.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me in the right direction. Adding `propertyMissing(String)` to the base class and throwing `MissingPropertyException` inside it prevents any further call to `get` on undefined variables, and that's what I was looking for.